# How are the verbs kosten and lehren used with 2 accusatives in these sentences?

Tags: grammatical-case, accusative

So I am reading Hammer's German Grammar and it says:

> Kosten and lehren are normally used with two accusatives:
>
> Der Flug hat **meinen Vater 5000 Euro** gekostet
>
> The flight cost my father 5000 euros

How are these two accusatives, I only see one accusative here and that is **5000 euros**.

**Meinen Vater** seems like an indirect object to me because it answers the question: To whom did the flight cost 5000 euros?

> Sie hat **mich Deutsch** gelehrt.
>
> She taught me German.

Same thing here. To whom did she teach German? To me, so it should be **mir** right?

Comment: German *does not have* direct or indirect objects. We have acc verbs, acc+acc verbs, dat verbs, gen verbs, acc+gen verbs, intransitive verbs, etc. etc. And yes, you must learn them with the verbs,

Answer (score 4):

The concept of direct and indirect object doesn't really work in German. If you want to ask for accusative, the question is *wen oder was*.

> Der Flug hat **wen** 5000 Euro gekostet? Meinen Vater.
>
> Der Flug hat meinen Vater **was** gekostet? 5000 Euro.

Same for *lehren*:

> Sie hat **wen** Deutsch gelehrt? Mich.
>
> Sie hat mich **was** gelehrt? Deutsch.

Usually that doesn't really help, if you're not a native speaker. You just need to learn the right case for the verbs.

Comment: Actually it is easy to tell that *meinen Vater* is accusative because of the ending of mein**en**. In the case of *5000 Euro*, it's not that obvious, but you see it if you replace it: *Der Flug hat meinen Vater ein**en** großen Betrag gekostet.*

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence does not answer “To whom did the flight cost 5000 euros?”, that’s a question in a different language. It answers „Wen hat der Flug 5000 Euro gekostet?“ That *kosten* and *lehren* take two accusative objects is exceptional, that’s why the book mentions them. But it is like it is.

Comment: That's right, but it is a bit circular, isn't it. Like "it is accusative... because it is accusative". - I don't blame you. Things in languages are often not to be explained logically (although many people keep asking "why") but rather "it's so, because it is".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, I don't disagree, but my point stands that it is indeed unusual that these verbs take two accusative objects, but they just do, and that's exactly why the grammar book mentions them.
Although now that I think about it, at least for *lehren* the historical reason for it being *mich* and not *mir* may be that it is/was a causative.